# PHP/SQL SELECT statement using asterisk

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am having trouble getting an sql request to work. Without giving more details than needed,

```
$db_query = mysql_query(" select years,avg,best,win,top10,champs from `profile` where PLAYERID = '$monkey_id'");
```

works fine. However,

```
$db_query = mysql_query(" select * from `profile` where PLAYERID = '$monkey_id'");
```

doesn't return any results. The only change is that I'm trying to pull all fields instead of just those few. I'm at a loss to explain this. I taught myself all this stuff, so it's always possible I'm doing something dumb.

Edit:
Here's the rest of the surrounding code:

```
$db_query_inside = mysql_query(" select * from `profile` where PLAYERID = $monkey_id");
$db_query = mysql_fetch_array($db_query_inside);
$years_prev = $db_query['years'];
$avg_prev = $db_query['avg'];
$best_prev = $db_query['best'];
$win_prev = $db_query['win'];
$top10_prev = $db_query['top10'];
$champs_prev = $db_query['champs'];
```

Edit again:
Still don't know why it wouldn't work with *, but I just got what I needed done by listing the specific fields. It doesn't end up with any sort of error that can be gleaned from

```
die(mysql_error())
```

so I'm just giving up and working on stuff that reacts rationally.

Comment: query seems fine. How do you fetch result from query result?

Comment: If the only thing you changed is replace fields to `*` then it is not possible.

Comment: Show some more code, it's probably the way you're building the array.

Comment: That's funny, the first query shouldn't work, because you have a field "avg" which should be quoted(it's a function-name).

Comment: is `$monkey_id` an integer or string?

Comment: Here's the rest of the code. To answer your questions first: @luckytaxi $monkey_id is an integer. I got rid of the quotes. @Dr.Molle it's not supposed to be a function name - the field is just called avg.

Comment: @Dr. Molle - `AVG` is not a reserved word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
$db_query = mysql_query(" select `profile` where PLAYERID = '$monkey_id'");
```

Comment: Or:    $db_query = mysql_query(" select `profile` where PLAYERID = '$monkey_id'");

Comment: Don't you need to ask for some fields? I don't know what's going on, because literally all I need to do to make it work is replace the * with field names.

Comment: That's mistaken. It's missing the field list and the FROM keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this, modify the following line to reflect below. See what the error says, if any. I tried it myself (your code) and it seems to work fine.

```
$db_query_inside = mysql_query(" select * from `profile` where PLAYERID = $monkey_id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This is the weird thing - it doesn't show an error. It just doesn't come up with anything. I guess it sees the result as just a null resource result or something.